# Finding the dy/dx of a complicated function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I need urgent help on this question. I have no clue how to solve it as it's very complicated to me. The question is the following:

Given
$y=\frac{2xy}{x^2 + y}$
find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Have you ever done implicit differentiation before?

Comment: @GeorgeMoore I have, however, what confuses me is that I need to use the quotient rule to find the derivative on the right side and when I do, the dy/dx when I take the derivative of y on the numerator gets me confused. As I have no idea how to move it to one side or factor it out

Answer (score 3):

$$y=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y}\implies x^2+y=2x\implies y=2x-x^2~\forall~y\neq 0$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for solving, however, (no offence) I have no idea what that is

Comment: @John, are you familar with the formula $\dfrac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}~\forall~n\in\Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: My answer solves your problem when $y\neq 0$. To get a more general derivative however, you'll require a lot of manual work (easy but lengthy). I recommend using Wolfram|Alpha for such computations as it saves you time.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not. I'm in twelfth grade and I just want to thank you for your help anyway. I know how to do implicit differentiation however, we were never taught how to solve it when you have a derivative in quotient form like the above.

Comment: @John, ah, nice to hear from a fellow 12th grader. I myself gave my 12th grade finals about two months before. :D

Comment: @John, [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules) might help you. :)

Comment: No way! Haha, thanks so much! :D

Comment: @John, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel y in numerator on each side and express $ y=f(x) $

$ y = 2 x - x^2 $

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2 - 2 x  $

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides w.r.t. x (by applying quotient rule):

\begin{align}
y' & =\frac{(2y+2xy')(x^2+y)-2xy(2x+y')}{(x^2+y)^2}\\
&=\frac{2x^2y+2x^3y'+2y^2+2xyy' -4x^2y -2xyy'}{(x^2+y)^2}\\
&= \frac{2x^3y'+2y^2-2x^2y}{(x^2+y)^2}\\
(x^2+y)^2y' &= 2x^3y'+2y^2 -2x^2y\\
y' &= \frac{2y^2 -2x^2y}{(x^2+y)^2-2x^3}
\end{align}

Comment: You are welcome. If this question happens to be an exercise of implicit differentiation then I think doing such exercises is necessary to make you familiar with the topic. By the way just a remainder: you can accept an answer by clicking the tick (if you don't know), so that you and the owner both get reputation, and others who have the same problem can read the answer.